# Split text into sentences, but skip quoted content

Tags: ruby, regex

I want to split some text into sentences using regular expression (using Ruby). It does not need to be accurate, so cases such as "Washington D.C." can be ignored.

However I have an requirement that, if the sentence is quoted (by single or double quotes), then it should be ignored.

Say I have the following text:

> Sentence One. "Wow." said Alice. Senetence Three.

It should be split into three sentences:

> Sentence One.
>   "Wow." said Alice.
>   Sentence Three.

Currently I have `content.scan(/[^\.!\?\n]*[\.!\?\n]/)`, but I have problem with quotes.

**UPDATE:**

The current answer can hit some performance issue. Try the following:

```
'Alice stood besides the table. She looked towards the rabbit, "Wait! Stop!", said Alice'.scan(regexp)
```

Would be nice if someone can figure out how to avoid it. Thanks!

Comment: Sounds like a homework assignment.

Comment: @theTinMan well it's not, it's my hobby website, to mimick Github line comments: http://pastebin.com/pR1My4Kz . I am bad with regular expression. Even if it is, did you find a similar question? Lastly, I think use regular expression to split sentences are not localized at all.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

How about this:

```
result = subject.scan(
    /(?:      # Either match...
     "[^"]*"  # a quoted sentence
    |         # or
     [^".!?]* # anything except quotes or punctuation.
    )++       # Repeat as needed; avoid backtracking
    [.!?\s]*  # Then match optional punctuation characters and/or whitespace./x)
```

Comment: Hi, just found out that this can run into issue of the scan never stops. For example `'Alice stood besides the table. She looked towards the rabbit, "Wait! Stop!", said Alice'.scan(rg)`. Do you know enough to avoid this?

Comment: @lulalala: Yes. The problem is that your example sentence doesn't stop with a punctuation character, which this regex requires. The problem with the current regex is that it's prone to [catastrophic backtracking](http://www.regular-expressions.info/catastrophic.html). There are two ways to fix this: 1.) don't require trailing punctuation, 2.) allow the match to fail more quickly if trailing punctuation is missing (which would mean that `Wait! Stop!` would become a valid match). Which version would you prefer?

Comment: Thanks so much. I guess the first one. The text I analyze can be quite wild and sometimes the period is just not there.

Comment: @lulalala: OK, please try the new version.